# Create a paper in SAS

Tags: sas, ods

Here is another issue I'm facing with SAS:
I have to write a full paper/report in SAS and can't find how to do so. So I already have a multitude of coding (to clean the data, create some new variable, merge three datasets, etc etc etc. I also made some tables and a few plots in the whole process). Now what I need to do for the project is: Write a scientific paper of a only a few pages (introduction, methodology, results, discussion, ...) in SAS. (I think the teacher said something about `ods text ="blablabla..."` to insert the text.) And of course use some of the tables/plots from my previous coding in this. This paper should be exported into a pdf file. 
I was thinking of using

```
ODS TRACE ON;
...
ODS TRACE OFF;
```

for the tables I made (code for the creation of the tables is between those two lines of code). But then I just don't understand how I can re-use this output later on when creating my pdf-paper with:

```
ODS PDF FILE ='c:\...'
...
ODS PDF CLOSE;
```

I was hoping I could just 'trace' all of the tables and plots I needed in my code. And than open this pdf file, add some titles, some text, some of the tables/plots in between the text, and close the pdf file. However, I have a bad feeling it isn't as simple as that. :'(

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use a Jupyter Notebook? You have a steep learning curve with the code itself and getting nice clean tables is enough work. If you search on lexjansen.com for examples on how to create clean tables that'll help you get started.

Comment: "Write a scientific paper of a only a few pages in SAS" i know what SAS support would say to that topic, but if you want anything in one file just write ODS PDF FILE in you first line an CLOSE it in the last line of your program.

Comment: @Reeza: It should really be in Sas and the table designs etc are not the important thing.

Comment: @Lee: The whole code shouldn't be in this paper. It really has to look as a small scientific paper. So no codes, only the output of some of the tables and plots (not all) and text in between.

Comment: That is what ODS normally does only output. Only output of procedures and datasteps but no code. If any code appears in ODS you have rerouted log to ODS.

Comment: Jupyter notebooks use SAS + Markdown to make it easier to create reports. Have you worked with Jupyter before and found it's an issue or problematic somehow? I created all the reports here using SAS, so have done it before and there are ways : https://open.alberta.ca/dataset?q=%22Primary%20health%20care%20-%20community%20profiles%22

Comment: Also, table designs will definitely be important, most journals I've ever submitted to have quite specific standards. You could also look at using latex if you're so inclined.